# Back button redirects to login screen

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using `react-native-router-flux` as my navigator. The issue that I am facing is probably quite simple but I can't seem to put my head into it. When the user logins in to the app, he/she gets redirected to the main dashboard scene. From there, if the user presses the android back button, the app should logically close instead of navigating back to the login screen again but I can't grasp the missing logic for achieving this.

Router:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native'
import { Scene, Router, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'
import Login from '../pages/login'
import Dashboard from '../pages/dashboard'
import NavigationDrawer from './navigationDrawer'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

const Menu = () => {
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={ () => Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', open: value => !value }) }>
      <Icon
        name="view-headline"
        size={30}
        color="white"
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

class NavigationRouter extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <Router>
        <Scene initial key="login" component={Login} hideNavBar/>
        <Scene key="drawer" component={NavigationDrawer} open={false} >
          <Scene key="main">
            <Scene initial key="dashboard" title="Dashboard" navigationBarStyle={Styles.navigationBarStyle} component={Dashboard} hideNavBar={false}
              renderLeftButton={() => (<Menu/>)} />
          </Scene>
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

const Styles = {
  navigationBarStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#fda21d"
  }
}
export default NavigationRouter;
```

Dashboard Scene:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  BackAndroid
} from 'react-native'
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
      if (this.props.title === 'Dashboard') {
        console.log("pressed");
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
      [...]
  }
```

I tried using the BackAndroid API that Facebook provided but it is also not working at all.

Comment: I think easy solution would be to use `Actions` with reset type. On login success try `Actions.drawer({type: 'reset'});`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did in my app using redux.

```
componentWillMount() {
  BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._backAndroid);
}

componentWillUnMount() {
  BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._backAndroid);
}

_backAndroid = () => {
  if (this.props.scene !== "home") {
    try {
      Actions.pop();
      return true;
    } catch(err) {
      return false; // exit app without prompt
    }
  }

  Alert.alert(
    'Exit',
    'Are you sure you want to exit?',
    [
      { text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => {} },
      { text: 'Yes', onPress: () => {BackAndroid.exitApp()}},
    ]
  );
  return true;
}
```

my reducer

```
import { ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const initialState = {
  scene: {},
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // focus action is dispatched when a new screen comes into focus
    case ActionConst.FOCUS:
      return {
        ...state,
        scene: action.scene.name,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: I decided not to use Redux on this app because the app is not that complicated. Can I achieve this without it?

Comment: Instead of redux you can have your own reducer as shown in this example https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/DETAILED_EXAMPLE.md. But I'm not sure if that solves your problem.

Comment: when I try to check if props.title === "dashboard" I get undefined. It seems like BackAndroid API fires then executes the code the I have written

Comment: That's one of the reason why used redux, to identify the current scene.

Answer (score 0):

Reason I am answering my question even though Vinayr's one is marked as correct is only because I wrote it a tad bit differently (without Redux).

In my navigation router I added a reducer function as mentioned in the accepted answer and I aslo added the BackAndroid function there.

Code:

```
const reducerCreate = params => {
    const defaultReducer = Reducer(params);
    return (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
          case ActionConst.FOCUS:
            if (action.scene.name === "dashboard") {
              BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
                return BackAndroid.exitApp()
              })
            }
            break;
          default:
            return;
        }
        return defaultReducer(state, action);
    }
};

class NavigationRouter extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <Router createReducer={reducerCreate}>
      [...]
  }
```